# Updating Table Totals with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently added some functionality to a table using jQuery to allow users to add/delete table rows on the fly which is working well. However in doing so I broke the automatic calculation of totals based on the values enter into some cells in the table rows and for the life of me I can't work out how I broke it nor how to fix it.

I've also noticed that deleting a table row doesn't update the totals either (this was the new feature that I added).

Here's the script that runs that calculates the average number of hours per week for a single row - it should also update the total moderate or high field at the bottom of the table at the same time:

```
$(window).load(function(){
//Sum Table Cell and Map

$('#lastYear')
.on('change', 'select', calc)
.on('keyup', 'input', calc);

function calc(){

    $('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').each(function(i,v){

        var $cel = $(v.cells);

        var $risk = $cel.eq(1).find('option:selected').val();
        var $numb = $cel.eq(2).find('input').val();
        var $weeks = $cel.eq(3).find('input').val();
        var $avg = ($numb * $weeks) / 52;
        var $avgRounded = Math.round( $avg * 10 ) / 10;

        $cel.eq(4).find('input').val($avgRounded);

    });   

    var tot = {high:0,moderate:0}; 

    $('#lastYear tr:has(.risk) option:selected')
                .map(function(i){
                    var el = $(this).val();
                    var qty = parseFloat($('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last').prev().find('input').val());

                    if (!tot.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
                        tot[el] = 0;            
                    }
                    tot[el] += qty
                    return tot;
                }).get();

    // console.log(tot);
     $('#textfield4').val(tot.moderate.toFixed(1));
    $('#textfield5').val(tot.high.toFixed(1));

}

});//]]>
```

I've setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/bXtWC/1/) that shows the current functionality - you can see if generates the averages but generates a 'NaN' result for the totals when entering data, and when you click the Delete button it should also update the totals too.

Update: I think problem is that the script is looking for the last table cell then going to the previous one to get the value. This used to work when the average cell was the 2nd last cell, but not it's the 3rd last cell and I don't know how to look for that cell by name/id etc. Any ideas?

I'm new to Javascript and have spent almost a day trying to work this out so really appreciate some assistance with this.

Comment: This right here is what's breaking:

    `$('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last').prev().find('input').val()`

It is returning

    `"Add another activity"`

Comment: Thanks @ryan that makes sense as I've added another column for the new Delete button so the column that stores the average which I want to total is no longer the one before the last cell but now 2 before the last cell so it's grabbing the value of the "Add another activity button". Do you know the syntax to point it to the previous cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***`Working jsFiddle Demo`***](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/bXtWC/3/)

You have 2 `td` after your desired `input`. So you must call `prev` method twice:

```
var qty = parseFloat(
    $('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i).find('td:last')
        .prev().prev() // call prev method twice
        .find('input').val()
);
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise you could call the prev method more than once. Working well now. You don't know how to get the Delete button to also update the totals (i.e. force a recalculation when the delete button is pressed and a row disappears)?

Answer (score 1):

Mark your cells that store the average with eg a CSS class, than use that to find the cell within the row (rather than relying on td:last).

eg:

```
var row = $('#lastYear tr:has(.risk)').eq(i);  // if this is the TR you want..
var avgCell = row.find('td.averageCell');      // find a <TD class="averageCell">.
var avgValue = parseFloat( avgCell.val());
```

In general, relying on positions to find things is brittle & fairly difficult to maintain; it's better to use IDs (where there is only one) or CSS classes (where there may be multiple.) Both of these are efficient, as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - I agree. I inherited this so at the moment I need to work with what I've got but a rewrite would definitely use css classes. Many thanks